# Is it safe to assume DayOfWeek's numeric value?

Tags: c#, enums

I have the day of the week stored in a database, where Sunday = 1, Monday = 2 etc.

In a query from the database, I need to convert the day to `System.DayOfWeek`.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx):

> The value of the constants in this enumeration ranges from **DayOfWeek.Sunday** to **DayOfWeek.Saturday**. If cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates **DayOfWeek.Sunday**) to six (which indicates **DayOfWeek.Saturday**).

This means that after I query the data, I need to subtract 1 before I convert the result to `DayOfWeek`.

Is this safe?
Or do I need to worry about the numeric values of `DayOfWeek` changing?

Comment: Yes, When it is documented as `its value ranges from zero to six`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, this safe, you should not worry about the values changing. Here's how the enum is defined:

```
public enum DayOfWeek
{
    Sunday = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6
}
```

If those values change in the BCL, a hell lot of a code will break.

Comment: I'm sorry, but am I the only one who's completely perplexed, that these have been written in alphabetical order, instead of numerical and/or starting from the beginning of the week (sunday or monday)?

Comment: I almost down voted you Darin, you made me think and it hurt my brain. Next time, why don't you list them in a proper order you monster! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes always safe,you can go back and front :

```
return DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
```

and

```
return DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
```