# Get last/next week Wednesday date in C#

Tags: c#

How would I get last week Wednesday and next week Wednesday's date in C#:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   CurrentDate.Text = "Today's Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
   CurrentRent.Text = "Current Rent Date: "; // last wednesday
   NextRent.Text = "Next Rent Date: "; // next wednesday
}
```

Comment: What if today is Wednesday?

Comment: @TimS. - then it displays today's date

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To find the next Wednesday just keep adding days until you find one.  To find the previous Wednesday just keep subtracting days until you get to one.

```
DateTime nextWednesday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
while (nextWednesday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    nextWednesday = nextWednesday.AddDays(1);
DateTime lastWednesday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
while (lastWednesday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    lastWednesday = lastWednesday.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: +1, much cleaner answer than what I gave. Would recommend using this or the other answer that is similar.

Comment: Two of those lines need to be changed. It should read `nextWednesday = nextWednesday.AddDays(1);` and the like for lastWednesday, else you'll have infinite loops going on.

Comment: An alternative would be just find nextWednesday as shown, then .AddDays(-7) to get lastWednesday instead of another while loop.

Answer (score 11):

Use the AddDays routine:

```
        // increment by the number of offset days to get the correct date
        DayOfWeek desiredDay = DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
        int offsetAmount = (int) desiredDay - (int) DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
        DateTime lastWeekWednesday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7 + offsetAmount);
        DateTime nextWeekWednesday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7 + offsetAmount);
```

That should do it!

NOTE: If it is a Monday, "Last Wednesday" is going to give you the very last Wednesday that occurred, but "Next Wednesday" is going to give you the Wednesday 9 days from now! If you wanted to get the Wednesday in two days instead you would need to use the "%" operator. That means the second "nextweek" statement would read "(7 + offsetAmount) % 7".

Comment: That doesn't work. If I run it I get last Thursday and next Thursday. A bit more complicated than that.

Comment: Unless today isn't Wednesday, but the DayOfWeek should help with that. Check MSDN for it. :D http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: ^ lol yeah, and that got upvoted. A lot of close readers here.

Comment: Right, I haven't been using stack overflow for very long but I suppose I should know by now not to post an answer till I'm finished writing it. Sorry about that!

Comment: @drew_w that's not a big deal. But your new code doesn't work either. The issue (I annoyingly discovered a few minutes ago) is that the DayOfWeek enum is ordered alphabetically rather than by the conventional ordering (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday ect, it's Friday, Monday, Sat, Sun) so that arithmetic won't actually work. Instead you have to do a long hand if-else or switch :(

Comment: @evanmcdonnal it looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670399/is-it-safe-to-assume-dayofweeks-numeric-value shows that numeric values should have direct relationship to the actual day of the week. I'm checking my arithmatic for each of the days but I think if I get it right it should work.

Comment: @drew_w yeah you might be right about that. I was just looking at the msdn doc, it didn't have the int values, just assumed those were ascending.

Comment: The math is not correct here... I am using unit tests and this is not working... is this not supposed to work for Sunday? I found that to get it to work, the extra `-7` is not necessary.

Answer (score 7):

You could create 2 DateTime Extension methods, that can be used with a DayOfWeek parameter:

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{
    public static DateTime GetPreviousWeekDay(this DateTime currentDate, DayOfWeek dow)
    {
        int currentDay = (int)currentDate.DayOfWeek, gotoDay = (int)dow;
        return currentDate.AddDays(-7).AddDays(gotoDay-currentDay);
    }

    public static DateTime GetNextWeekDay(this DateTime currentDate, DayOfWeek dow)
    {
        int currentDay = (int)currentDate.DayOfWeek, gotoDay = (int)dow;
        return currentDate.AddDays(7).AddDays(gotoDay - currentDay);
    }
}
```

Which can then be used as follows:

```
DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2017, 01, 21);

Console.WriteLine(testDate.GetPreviousWeekDay(DayOfWeek.Wednesday));
Console.WriteLine(testDate.GetNextWeekDay(DayOfWeek.Wednesday));
```

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)` and `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)` is how you can do arithmetic, assuming you are on Wednesday. If you aren't, what you would need to do is use the `DayOfWeek` property to determine the number of days (positive and negative) that you would need to determine which day is 'Wednesday'. Then you can pass that value into `AddDays`.

For instance, if today was tuesday, you would `AddDays(-6)` for last Wednesday and `AddDays(8)` for next Wednesday.

I'll leave you the task of calculating those.

Comment: I think he's looking for Wednesdays that are a week apart. The question is a bit vague, though...

Comment: perhaps, which is why i didn't really delve into the nitty gritty, just how the "how" to approach solving

Answer (score 3):

Based on Servy's answer, here's an extension method which will return the desired day/date:

```
    public static DateTime GetPrevious(this DateTime date, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        var lastDay = date.AddDays(-1);
        while (lastDay.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek)
        {
            lastDay = lastDay.AddDays(-1);
        }

        return lastDay;
    }

    public static DateTime GetNext(this DateTime date, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        var nextDay = date.AddDays(+1);
        while (nextDay.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek)
        {
            nextDay = nextDay.AddDays(+1);
        }

        return nextDay;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to calculate it:

```
DateTime day = DateTime.Today;
while (day.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    day = day.AddDays(-1);
var currentRent = day;
var nextRent = day.AddDays(7);
```

Note that if today is Wednesday, this will show `currentRent` as today, not `nextRent` as today. If you want this reversed, you can reverse the logic.

```
DateTime day = DateTime.Today;
while (day.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    day = day.AddDays(1);
var currentRent = day.AddDays(-7);
var nextRent = day;
```

Comment: The code here is wrong I think. If today is Tuesday, you will get Wednesday as tomorrow when what you want is next weeks Wednesday

Comment: @DarrenKopp Hm. I took it to mean, that he wanted to find Wednesdays one week apart. I.e. weekly rent, not bi-weekly. In the bi-weekly case, there's an ambiguity without knowing *which* week it is. E.g. if it's a Wednesday, is the rent due today or next week?

Comment: perhaps, only the OP knows for sure :/

Comment: To be a bit more clearer - rent payments are taken weekly. Next rent week would be the next Wednesday and last rent week would be last Wednesday.

Comment: That doesn't really clear anything up to me, due to ambiguities in what "last" and "next" mean when referring to dates in English. Either see if my code does what you want, or edit your question to include example inputs ("today" dates) and outputs ("last" and "next" dates) in your question.

Answer (score 2):

This will work. You need to calculate the difference in days between your provided date and the nearest Wednesday, and calculate last/next Wednesday based on whether or not the difference is greater than zero.

```
int difference = date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
DateTime lastWednesday = difference > 0 ? date.AddDays(-1 * difference) : date.AddDays(-1 * (7 + difference));
DateTime nextWednesday = lastWednesday.AddDays(7);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner to accomplish the same. It is somewhat mind-boggling to understand how that actually works but it does:

Getting next Wednesday:

```
 dt.AddDays(-(int)(dt.AddDays(-4).DayOfWeek) + 6);
```

Getting last Wednesday

```
 dt.AddDays(-(int)(dt.AddDays(-3).DayOfWeek));
```

In both cases, it will return the day itself when it is Wednesday.
This works for any weekdays, just adjust the number in the AddDays() call.
For example for Friday:

Getting next Friday

```
 dt.AddDays(-(int)(dt.AddDays(-6).DayOfWeek) + 6);
```

Getting last Friday

```
 dt.AddDays(-(int)(dt.AddDays(-5).DayOfWeek));
```

Update:
Here's a piece of code that works based on the above.
Logic from above has been updated as follows: In the original code, if today is Monday, "last Monday" would return today.   This code has been updated so that if today is Monday, and you ask for last Monday, it will return the Monday 7 days ago:

```
// Returns last Monday, last Tuesday, etc.
// dt is today's date
// offset is 0 for last Sunday, -1 for last Monday, -2 for last Tuesday, etc.. to -6 for last Saturday
// If today is Monday, then last Monday is the Monday 7 days ago.
DateTime GetLast(DateTime dt, int offset) {
     dt = dt.AddDays(-1);
     return dt.AddDays(-(int)(dt.AddDays(offset).DayOfWeek));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `DayOfWeek` enum along with an if-else structure of switch statement to determine how many days to add/subtract for your dates. It's tedious coding but simple.

```
DateTime nextRent;
DateTime lastRent;
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
{
   nextRent = today.AddDays(7);
   lastRent = today.AddDays(-7);
}
else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
{
   nextRent = today.AddDays(6);
   lastRent = today.AddDays(-8);
}
//ect for all days
```

Comment: A very comprehensive answer Evan, +1.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with some of the answers is that the DayoyOfWeek is an enum  with values 0-6. When a subsequent day of week equates to Sunday (enum value = 0), but you gave a Tuesday (enum value=2), and you want next tuesday, the calculation goes wrong if you just peform a calculation.

The class with two methods which I cam up with for my own use on a project I am working on is.

```
public static class DateHelper
{
    public static DateTime GetDateForLastDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek DOW, DateTime DATE)
    {
        int adjustment = ((int)DATE.DayOfWeek < (int)DOW ? 7 : 0);
        return DATE.AddDays(0- (((int)(DATE.DayOfWeek) + adjustment) - (int)DOW));
    }

    public static DateTime GetDateForNextDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek DOW, DateTime DATE)
    {
        int adjustment = ((int)DATE.DayOfWeek < (int)DOW ? 0 : 7);
        return DATE.AddDays(((int)DOW) - ((int)(DATE.DayOfWeek)) + adjustment);
    }
}
```

The XUnit tests proving the code above works.

```
public class DateHelperUnitTests
{

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 7, 2020, 1, 7)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 8,  2020, 1, 7)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 9,  2020, 1, 7)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 10, 2020, 1, 7)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 11, 2020, 1, 7)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 12, 2020, 1, 7)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 13, 2020, 1, 7)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 14, 2020, 1, 14)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 15, 2020, 1, 14)]
    public void GetDateForLastDayOfWeek_MultipleValues_Pass(
        int InputYear, int InputMonth, int InputDay,
        int ExpectedYear, int ExpectedMonth, int ExpectedDay)
    {
        DateTime DateToTest = new DateTime(InputYear, InputMonth, InputDay);
        DateTime NewDate = DateHelper.GetDateForLastDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DateToTest);
        DateTime DateExpected = new DateTime(ExpectedYear,ExpectedMonth,ExpectedDay);

        Assert.True(0 == DateTime.Compare(DateExpected.Date, NewDate.Date));
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 7, 2020, 1, 14)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 8, 2020, 1, 14)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 9, 2020, 1, 14)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 10, 2020, 1, 14)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 11, 2020, 1, 14)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 12, 2020, 1, 14)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 13, 2020, 1, 14)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 14, 2020, 1, 21)]
    [InlineData(2020, 1, 15, 2020, 1, 21)]
    public void GetDateForNextDayOfWeek_MultipleValues_Pass(
        int InputYear, int InputMonth, int InputDay,
        int ExpectedYear, int ExpectedMonth, int ExpectedDay)
    {
        DateTime DateToTest = new DateTime(InputYear, InputMonth, InputDay);
        DateTime NewDate = DateHelper.GetDateForNextDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DateToTest);
        DateTime DateExpected = new DateTime(ExpectedYear, ExpectedMonth, ExpectedDay);

        Assert.True(0 == DateTime.Compare(DateExpected.Date, NewDate.Date));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved answer from Servy.  You need to actually set the nextWednesday or lastWednesday dates to the new date in the while loop, otherwise it goes into an infinite loop

```
DateTime nextWednesday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
while (nextWednesday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    nextWednesday = nextWednesday.AddDays(1);
DateTime lastWednesday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
while (lastWednesday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    lastWelastWednesday.AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static DateTime FindPreviousDayOfWeek(DateTime fromDate, DayOfWeek findDay, 
        bool skipSame = false)
    {
        if (fromDate.DayOfWeek < findDay)
            fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(-((int)fromDate.DayOfWeek - 1 + (int)findDay));
        else if (fromDate.DayOfWeek > findDay)
            fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(-((int)fromDate.DayOfWeek - (int)findDay));
        else if (fromDate.DayOfWeek == findDay && skipSame == true)
            fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(-7);

        return fromDate;
    }
```

the skipSame variable does not include the current day if it is the saem as the desired day.

Answer (score 0):

this extension method should do the trick for whatever dayofweek

```
   public static class DateTimeExtensions
    {
        public static DateTime LastDayOfWeek(this DateTime _date, DayOfWeek dayofweek)
        {
            return _date.AddDays(-1 * ((_date.DayOfWeek - dayofweek) % 7)).Date;
        }

        public static DateTime NextDayOfWeek(this DateTime _date, DayOfWeek dayofweek)
        {
            return _date.LastDayOfWeek(dayofweek).AddDays(7).Date;
        }
    }
```

usage

```
var lastWendsday = DateTime.Now.LastDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
```